# Why can't I write a value to a variable that belongs to a different module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 `.py` files.

File `a.py`:

```
some_boolean = True
```

File `b.py`:

```
from a import *
def blah():
    if some_boolean:
        do_something()
    some_boolean = not some_boolean
```

The code works perfectly fine without the `some_boolean = not some_boolean` line, but as soon as I add it back in I'm getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'some_boolean' referenced before assignment`.

I've been bashing my head for hours now and I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do qualified import of `a` and use the full name `a.some_boolean`:

```
import a

def blah():
    if a.some_boolean:
        do_something()
    a.some_boolean = not a.some_boolean
```

I your code `some_boolean = not some_boolean` tries to create a new local variable. This does not work because the name `some_boolean` is used for a local variable and shadows the global variable of the same name.
In general, you should never use the same name for a local and global variable.

Comment: the `global` keyword would also solve this issue, though it's an even worse idea than shadowing global names.

Comment: Never use `global`. ;) But it would not change the value in `a`. Looks like the OP would like have `a.some_boolean` available program-wide.